# What is the long-run variance of xt? Does it depend on θ? If so, how?

Tags: time-series, variance

x_t=(1+ θL)*ε_t,ε_t  ~ iid N (0,σ^2)

What is the long-run variance of x_t? Does it depend on θ? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jefferson. Please explain: what is q??  Have you searched our site for [exercises about variances of ARIMA processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=arima%20variance%20%5bself-study%5d&searchOn=3) for answers?

Comment: Ah sorry that is theta.

Comment: I couldn't make sense as to why you undid the $\LaTeX$ expression that increased the readability. Anyway, it's your post.

Comment: Because I had to edit the post because of the typo (q-theta) and then it turned back to this form. But I also prefer the latex version. sorry

Comment: You can improve the readability of your questions and answers using Mathjax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jefferson: It's best to write out the expression without the lag operator
and calculate the variance directly using properties of variance. The MA(1) is
:

$x_t = \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} $

The variance of the first term is $\sigma^2$ and the variance of the second term is $\theta^2 \sigma^2$. There is no covariance between the two terms so they just add and one obtains $\sigma^2 + \theta^2 \sigma^2 = \sigma^2(1+\theta^2)$. If you're not familar with the steps, it's probably best to take a
mathematical statistics class where these concepts are covered.